# Should images be cropped and if so, how far?

Tags: discussion, images

On [What town is meant by the location Gorn. Laknic?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/13748/2586), a comment suggests to crop down the images.

I certainly could, but is that useful to do here?

(I ask since it would take some time to download each image crop and upload again.)  I gave the context in full for the images when posting since it might shed light on the answer or help a future researcher that came upon them and wanted info beyond the questions.

If not helpful, what advantage does it serve to go back and crop?

The full resolution is only given if clicked, so perhaps the large files are ok?

And if desired to crop, how far to crop down?

Show just the word, or include any context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to minimize chances of infringing any copyright that might apply, and to keep questions focused, I think images should normally be cropped as far as is sensible.

If only a single word in an image is being asked about then, to me, sensible cropping would be that word and a few words around it, hopefully some including the same letters.

If potential answerers need more examples of letters, or to know missing column headers, then they seem to always ask for more, and questions are easily edited.

Comment: Agreed. I would aim to make sure that the specific text being asked about is, if at all possible, readable within the question, without having to click for a full-res version. In the linked example the relevant text was too small to read, at least on my screen. I'd crop those images much as suggested, but perhaps link to one or more full ones in case extended context became relevant.

Comment: It's also kinder to those with restricted bandwidth to crop.